# Horizontal scrollable div with auto multicol text wrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, horizontal-scrolling

I have some songs' lyrics that I'd like to display in a container that expand in width and height in the remaining space of the screen as much as possible (to the edge of the screen bottom and right), and I want the scrolling area (if needed) to always be horizontal (no vertical scrolling). If the lyrics are longer than the height available, I would like the remaining text to be display in a second column (at the top). The width of the column aren't fixed either, they are defined by the longuest line (no line should be wrapped). The number of column depend on the length of the text.

So far, I have manage to get something like that :

```css
flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* <-- allows multi-line flex container */
  height: 250px;
  background-color: silver;
}
flex-item {
  flex: 0 0 0px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<flex-container>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>But you must try, try and try, try and try</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You'll succeed at last, mmh, yeah</flex-item>
  <flex-item>Persecution you must fear</flex-item>
  <flex-item>Win or lose you're about to get your share</flex-item>
  <flex-item>Got your mind set on a dream</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it though hard it may seem now</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>But you must try, try and try, try and try</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You'll succeed at last, I know it</flex-item>
  <flex-item>Listen, Rome was not built in a day</flex-item>
  <flex-item>Opposition will come your way</flex-item>
  <flex-item>But the harder the battle, you see</flex-item>
  <flex-item>Is the sweeter the victory now</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>But you must try, try and try, try and try</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You'll succeed at last</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>But you must try, try and try, try and try</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You'll succeed at last</flex-item>
  <flex-item>I know it</flex-item>
  <flex-item>(You can get it if you really want) don't I show it</flex-item>
  <flex-item>(You can get it if you really want) don't give up now</flex-item>
  <flex-item>(You can get it if you really want) keep on trying</flex-item>
</flex-container>
```

The major problem with it, is that it requires to put every line of text between HTML tags which is possible to do on the server side but I'm not sure is a really good idea. Can you confirm ? Do you know what would be the right way to do something like that ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare some constant height to your parent div and add this CSS property to parent div in which songs lyrics are.

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Then scroll bar will appear on that div.(Make sure to declare constant height of div otherwise it will not work properly).

Comment: The OP wants no vertical scrolling (because it makes it hard to read). So he or she wants multicol done right.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the scrolling area (if needed) to always be horizontal (no
>   vertical scrolling).

To achieve that, I added `overflow-y: hidden;` and `overflow-x: auto;`.

> The major problem with it, is that it requires to put every line of
>   text between HTML tags which is possible to do on the server side but
>   I'm not sure is a really good idea.

I think you have to wrap each *verse* with an `html` tag, as you did. I don't think there is a better way.

Also, I added `max-height: 250px;` to `flex-container` to demonstrate `overflow-x`'s functionality. You might want to change it with `height: 100%` in your setup.

```css
flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: silver;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 175px;
}

flex-item {
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<flex-container>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>But you must try, try and try, try and try</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You'll succeed at last, mmh, yeah</flex-item>
  <flex-item>Persecution you must fear</flex-item>
  <flex-item>Win or lose you're about to get your share</flex-item>
  <flex-item>Got your mind set on a dream</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it though hard it may seem now</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>But you must try, try and try, try and try</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You'll succeed at last, I know it</flex-item>
  <flex-item>Listen, Rome was not built in a day</flex-item>
  <flex-item>Opposition will come your way</flex-item>
  <flex-item>But the harder the battle, you see</flex-item>
  <flex-item>Is the sweeter the victory now</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>But you must try, try and try, try and try</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You'll succeed at last</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You can get it if you really want</flex-item>
  <flex-item>But you must try, try and try, try and try</flex-item>
  <flex-item>You'll succeed at last</flex-item>
  <flex-item>I know it</flex-item>
  <flex-item>(You can get it if you really want) don't I show it</flex-item>
  <flex-item>(You can get it if you really want) don't give up now</flex-item>
  <flex-item>(You can get it if you really want) keep on trying</flex-item>
</flex-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough room in a comment for my response, so I'm posting this response using the Answer feature. This is not an answer, unfortunately.

What the OP is asking for, I think, is CSS Multicol done correctly.

Columns are currently implemented incorrectly. You get to choose only the minimum (not maximum) column width. The user must scroll manually from the bottom of one column of text up to the start of the next column, so reading long text is difficult.

It is not difficult to design columns to grow intelligently, at any viewport width. Here is exactly how columns should be handled:

If there is very little text, show one column only (of a fixed given width), until the viewport height is reached. At that point there is one column, filling the available height. Then show two columns, the first one as high as the viewport, the second one growing from top down as the first one did.

If the entire width of the viewport is exceeded with one or more columns, show the same column layout, but with a horizontal scrollbar added.

This design supports easy reading of any text. I hope a CSS designer reads this.